# VBA: Find number of occurrences in one column based on number of occurrences in a second column

Tags: excel, vba, countif, find-occurrences

I need to figured out a way to count the number of times a number appears in Column B based on it matching a value in column A.

Example:

```
Column A       Column B    
2172223333    2172245555    
2172223333    2172245555    
2172234444    2172245555    
2172234444    2172245555    
2172285544    2172245555
```

So in this example I would need to calculate that

`2172245555` occurs 2 times in relation to `2172223333`

`2172245555` occurs 2 times in relation to `2172234444`

`2172245555` occurs 1 time in relation to `2172285544`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following formula in column C

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,B:B,B:B)
```

to get the occurences of the combinations.

[image]

---

Alternatively you can use in cell C2

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
```

… and copy it down.

---

Edit to proof my comment below:
[image]
see the last line here. `2172223333` occurs but the combination counts only the occurences of combinations of column A and B.

Comment: Sorry for not providing clear enough info.  Column B can change as well.

Comment: So might have 2172223333 further down the column with a different number in Column B, so I can't use a traditional COUNTIFS statement because it will count all of the times 2172223333 occurs in Column A, not just the # of times that 2172223333 occurs in relation to 2172245555. Then further down the column I would need to know how many times 2172223333 occurs again with a different number in column B, say 2172287777.

Comment: @BonnieZ No, it does exactly what you want. It only coun't the rows that have the same combination of column A and column B. Test it please. Note that `COUNTIFS` is not `COUNTIF`. `COUNTIFS` can check multiple criterias. See my edit for a proof.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a helper column that concatenates Columns A and B. This creates a *Composite Key* which you can then use in the `CountIf` function like so:

[image]

- Column C Formula: `=A2&B2`
- Column D Formula: `=COUNTIF($C$2:$C6,$C2)`
- Column E Formula: `=COUNTIF($C$2:$C2,$C2)`

**Note:** I added the running count Column (Column E) for kicks, so its not necessary, just another option you might want to pull out in the future.

Comment: Actually the reason why there is a `COUNTIFS` is that you don't have to do this ;)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ You are correct! Your answer was exactly what OP needed, but I just thought it may be useful for them to see the idea behind it. `Countis` while very powerful have always been a bit daunting to me (I am a simple fellow lol). Additionally, the concept of _composite keys_ can spark ideas for other useful tasks that readers may need and would find after coming across this post.